# oracle select two count values in one row

Tags: oracle

I need help with this select in oracle.  I have table with 2 columns: (table > date, value) for example:

```
1.1.2017, 16
1.1.2017, 16
1.1.2017, 16
1.1.2017, 17
1.2.2017, 16
1.2.2017, 16
1.2.2017, 17
1.2.2017, 17
1.3.2017, 16
```

Result must be:

```
1.1.2017 as date, 3 as count of 16, 1 as count of 17
1.2.2017, 2, 2
1.3.2017, 1, 0
```

Current SQL:

```
select date, count(value) from table group by date, value
```

However, this does not return the same date with one row with count of both values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional counting, something like this:

```
with
     your_table ( dt, value ) as (
       select to_date('1.1.2017', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 16 from dual union all
       select to_date('1.1.2017', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 16 from dual union all 
       select to_date('1.1.2017', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 16 from dual union all
       select to_date('1.1.2017', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 17 from dual union all
       select to_date('1.2.2017', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 16 from dual union all
       select to_date('1.2.2017', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 16 from dual union all
       select to_date('1.2.2017', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 17 from dual union all
       select to_date('1.2.2017', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 17 from dual union all
       select to_date('1.3.2017', 'mm.dd.yyyy'), 16 from dual
     )
--  end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select   dt, count(case value when 16 then 'x' end) as ct_16,
             count(case value when 17 then 'x' end) as ct_17
from     your_table
group by dt;

DT          CT_16  CT_17
----------  -----  -----
01/01/2017      3      1
01/02/2017      2      2
01/03/2017      1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

select date, value, count(value) from table group by date, value;